# Put output of SAGA algorithm of Processing model in R script

Tags: qgis, r, saga, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to combine the `Variogram Cloud` model of SAGA with an R script inside a Processing model.

First, the R script is:

```
##Vector processing=group
##showplots
##Layer=table
##X=Field Layer
##Y=Field Layer
plot(Layer[[X]], Layer[[Y]], xlab=X, ylab=Y)
```

Second, the Processing model:

[image]

where:

- `Shape` is a generic shapefile
- `attribute` is the attribute for the variogram calculation
- `distance` is just a number for the default distance of the SAGA algorithm

The output of the SAGA algorithm is a simple csv table, here a screenshot:

[image]

What I want to do now is to put inside the R script (in the model) the `Distance` and `Semivariance` columns as `x` and `y` axis.

The only way I found is to add manually `Distance` and `Semivariance` in the model:

[image]

So the question is: how can I add `default` x and y axes in the Rscript window?

I think link a dropdown menu for both `X` and `Y` where I can choose the column of and algorithm output.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because QGIS has no way of knowing and reading the names of the columns of the output of variogram cloud algorithm.